# Flow On Schedule

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, scheduled

I"ve created a flow that I'd like to run monthly on the 7th day of each month. How can I do this with scheduled apex. I have no experience writing apex from scratch. Any suggestions or starting off points appreciated. 
Thanks, 
Kris

Answer (score 6):

You *can* fire an autolaunched Flow using Scheduled Apex, but there's an easier way if you don't have experience writing code. Doug Ayers has a free, open source application called [Mass Action Scheduler](https://douglascayers.github.io/sfdx-mass-action-scheduler/):

> Declaratively schedule Process Builder, Flows, Quick Actions, Email Alerts, Workflow Rules, and Apex to process records from Reports and List Views.

You can use Mass Action Scheduler to schedule your Flow declaratively.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example of a trivial Schedulable class and how it can call an autolaunched flow

```
public with sharing class MySchedulable implements Schedulable {

  public void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
    //  Call FLOW to do actual work (no input args)
    new Flow.Interview.MyFlow(new Map<String,Object>()).start();

    //  Call FLOW w/ input args - keys are case sensitive to match Flow variables
    new Flow.Interview.MyOtherFlow(new Map<String,Object> {
       'myVar' => 'abc',
       'myVar2' => 65})
     .start();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

One trick you can use is to create a custom object, and attach a Process to it that has two actions (a) delay creating a new record, and (b) set a delayed scheduled action that calls the flow. After this, you just need to create a record, and it'll automatically call the schedule at the desired time, on repeat, until you delete whichever record is holding the last scheduled action.