# Run a Autolaunched Flow created with the new (winter '20) schedule option

Tags: visual-workflow, scheduled-apex, visual-flows, schedule

I have a flow as described in the title, created with [this feature](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_fbuilder_start.htm). If I click on the 'Run' button i receive the following error:

```
The flow failed to start because the provided values were not valid: Scheduled Flow could only be run from a schedule
```

If i try with the following code:

```
Map<String, Object> params = new Map<String, Object>();
Flow.Interview.FlowName thisFlow = new Flow.Interview.FlowName(params);
thisFlow.start();
```

I receive the same error (as expected):

```
System.FlowException: The flow failed to start because the provided values were not valid: Scheduled Flow could only be run from a schedule
```

I also tried as suggested in [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/221018/flow-on-schedule), by making a class like so:

```
public class Flow_Scheduler implements Schedulable {

    public void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
        Map<String, Object> params = new Map<String, Object>();
        Flow.Interview.Chargent_recurring_injector_for_scheduledBatchProcessing thisFlow = new Flow.Interview.Chargent_recurring_injector_for_scheduledBatchProcessing(params);
        thisFlow.start();
    }
}
```

and then launch it with:

```
System.schedule('my flow ' + String.valueOf(Datetime.now()), nextFireTime, new Flow_Scheduler());
```

and I receive the following:

```
The flow failed to start because the provided values were not valid: Scheduled Flow could only be run from a schedule
```

the same error message from the debug logs.

I need to run this flow with an "on-demand" fashion to make the testers job easier. What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: Unsure what constitutes "proper", but have you considered having two flows: one that does the work with the old start trigger, and one that has a scheduled start trigger which invokes the first flow?